# Insert paragraph between class brief and Public Member Functions

Tags: doxygen

I'd like to include a list of objects which use a given class near the top of the page for a class.  I'm generating that list via a code generator.

Currently I add a paragraph but this goes after all the member functions etc in the "Detailed Description" section.

Can't see a way to do this without sticking it in the brief which is not really what I want to do as that would end up being used in places outside of the class doc page.

e.g.

```
//! \class READ_WRITE
//!
//! \brief This keyword is used to mark a measurement object to be writeable. 
//! 
//! \par Used By
//! \ref INSTANCE
//! \ref MEASUREMENT
//!
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create with `doxygen -l` a DoxygenLayout.xml and by placing the `<detaileddescription...` in the class part more to the "top" of the class part you can get the detailed part higher on the page (I know this is not exactly what you want).
Please readup in the documentation and see if there is something in respect to what you would like to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks - that is good to know - I did read every item in the special commands section.  Had a bit of a look at the source code but it would take a while to figure out how it actually places the sections without running it under a debugger.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a way to put custom sections in the layout so probably the only way to do it is to either modify doxygen or generate XML and then generate the html manually.  Probably best option would be to add a \preamble command to doxygen or similar - though precise placement between some of the first few items would probably be handy

Comment: Feel free to create an enhancement request in the doxygen issues list (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/), will probably be hard to find a good solution though that will also work for other parts.

Comment: Thanks - added #7076